# App isn't building after update Firebase Performance SDK

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-performance

After update
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'`
Getting compile errors below....

> Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process /app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/debug/2
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/debug/2
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.tools.r8.D8Command$Builder.setIncludeClassesChecksum(Z)Lcom/android/tools/r8/BaseCompilerCommand$Builder;
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process /app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/debug/121
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/debug/121
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.tools.r8.D8Command$Builder.setIncludeClassesChecksum(Z)Lcom/android/tools/r8/BaseCompilerCommand$Builder;
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution : After remove `classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.2.52'` from project level gradle then issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I just rebuild the project, and it works again

Step 1: Go to Build
Step 2: Rebuild the Project
Step 3: Done!

[image]